# How to show progress status of requests response download into web page in Django

Tags: django, python-requests

I build an application in Django, and I have a function to get attendance log from a fingerprint machine, basically like this:

```
import requests
from xml.etree import ElementTree
def main(request):
    Key="xxxxxx"

    url="http://192.168.2.188:80"

    soapreq="<GetAttLog><ArgComKey xsi:type=\"xsd:integer\">"+Key+"</ArgComKey><Arg><PIN xsi:type=\"xsd:integer\">All</PIN></Arg></GetAttLog>"



    http_headers = {
        "Accept": "application/soap+xml,multipart/related,text/*",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8"

    }


    response = requests.post(url+"/iWsService",data=soapreq,headers=http_headers)

    root = ElementTree.fromstring(response.content)
```

Now, that process will be repeated for hundred++ fingerprint machines, and I need to display some kind of progress status and also error messages ( if any, like connection cannot be eastablished, etc) on a page, periodically and sequentially, after each events. I mean something like :

....

"machine 1 : download finished."

"downloading data from machine 2 .. Please wait "

"machine 2 : download finished."

...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what is the main hurdle you're facing. Can you try framing the question in a more precise way?

From what I understand, you want a page that changes dynamically based on something that's happening on the server. I think django may not be the best tool for that, as its basic use is to compute a full view in one go then display it. However, there are a few things that can be done.

The easiest (but not the best in terms of server load) would be to use Ajax requests from the webpage.

- Have a "main view" that loads the user-facing page as well as some JS libraries (e.g. jQuery), which will be used to query the server for progress.
- Have a "progress view" that displays the current status and that is queried from the main view via AJAX.

This is not the best architecture because you may end up reloading data from the server too often or not often enough. I would suggest to have a look at websockets, which allow you to keep a client-server connection open and use it when needed only, but there is no native support for them in django.

Comment: I'm still newbie to Django, so let me descibe the background.

Comment: I have fingerprint attendance machines on 100 offices. The devices exposes the att.log via a web service so I can requestand get XML response containing ID and checkin/checkout time, roughly 200 lines of checktime records, twice a day, and put them into DB  
  
  My question is what is the best approach to do that and get some kind of progress status of this "downloading" processes onto a page,so I can see which download is completed, or if  error occured (some machines probably down and the requests timed out).  
  
  maybe a python script (not in django-view)? Is celery relevant to this?

Comment: Celery looks relevant (I haven't tried it yet), and does support Django out of the box.
Otherwise, if you're using Django, have all your data in the database, you can write a simple Django view that queries the database and shows its status

Comment: I'll look into Celery. The status that I need is progress status of the downloading process of XML responses from those machines. The database roles would be after that.